# As3 flash text field resize vertically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, height, autosize

im making a chat app and I want to add individual pieces of textfields to an mc so that those textfields can be costumized by the users i.e. backgrounds, fonts, and stuff. and to do that I have to get the height of the textfield, because Im going to need it for placing the next textfields (height = Y of the next textfield)

I have tried multiline and wordwrap but it only shows 1 line...
I HAVE also TRIED AUTOSIZE = left
BUT... it adds a huge unecessary blank space at the end

heres the code
    enter code here`for (i=0; i

```
// Apply some text to the textfield
boxMC.txTitle.htmlText ="<div style='width:50px'>Instance:aefvasdfawe efaegfawegfaw     egawerg alejr joaej alejuf owirt a iajsejrt a aopeu rt tauwe taiej r aiejrt a mc"+nextYPos+"</div>";
//attach the newly created instance to the container
myContent.addChild(boxMC);
//set y value for next item
boxMC.txTitle.width = 100;
boxMC.txTitle.autoSize = "100";
boxMC.txTitle.wordWrap = true;
boxMC.txTitle.multiline = true;
nextYPos+=boxMC.txTitle.height;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed it... I think

```
 boxMC.txTitle.width = apW-30;
 boxMC.txTitle.wordWrap = true;
 boxMC.txTitle.multiline = true;
 if(boxMC.txTitle.textHeight == 15)
    { var theight = 9; }
 else { theight = 0; }

 boxMC.txTitle.height = boxMC.txTitle.textHeight + 4;
 myContent.addChild(boxMC);
 nextYPos+=boxMC.txTitle.textHeight + theight + 4 + 6;
```